# How can I convert simple string to Base64 in App Inventor 2?

Tags: encoding, base64, app-inventor

I've been searching through the Internet and I don't seem to find a way of converting a simple string into a Base64 string in MIT App Inventor 2.

All I can find are extensions to convert images to Base64, but not strings. Is there a way that I am not realizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the [tools extension](https://puravidaapps.com/tools.php) and its **Base64Encode** method:

[image]

Comment: How about decode funciton ? TaifunTools extension seems there is no decode function ..

Comment: try the [Cryptography extension](http://sunnythedeveloper.epizy.com/2020/04/25/asymmetriccryptography-an-extension-for-asymmetric-cryptography/) by vknow360